# What is a spherical Gaussian kernel?

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis

In [this paper](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/PDKernels.pdf) (page 8, Example 3), a spherical Gaussian kernel is defined by the formula $$K(\mathrm x,\mathrm y)=e^{-2\epsilon(1- \mathrm x\cdot\mathrm y)}$$ where $\mathrm{x,y}\in S^{n-1}\subseteq\mathbb R^n$. It is said to be an example of a zonal kernel.

> What is the meaning of such a kernel? Where does it naturally come from?

As I understand it, the importance of the ordinary Gaussian in $\mathbb R^n$ comes from its appearance in probability distributions. Also, it is an eigenvector of the Fourier transform, which easily convinces me of its importance. Ideally, I am hoping there might be some similar characterizations of the spherical Gaussian.

Another thought: I would expect the geodesic distance $\arccos\mathrm{x}\cdot\mathrm{y}$ to appear somewhere in the formula of a spherical Gaussian kernel. Instead, $1-\mathrm{x}\cdot\mathrm{y}$ appears, which could be some kind of an approximation. This leads me to wonder:

> Is the definition above the natural one (mathematically speaking)?

Also, it seems that the key feature of $\mathbb R^n$ that makes the existence of the ordinary Gaussian possible is its non-compactness, which leads me to think that a spherical Gaussian might not be a natural thing at all ...

Good references and/or illuminating thoughts would be very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried e-mailing the author of the paper with this question? fasshauer@iit.edu

Comment: @William: Not yet. I am currently busy with other issues, but I will consider doing so.